# Docker-Compose / Azure WebApp / Nest.JS & Nuxt.js : got ENOTFOUND trying to fetch backend server container with axios

Tags: azure, docker, docker-compose, nestjs, nuxtjs

i'm new here and i hope to be able to find a solution to my problem :)

So,

I am developing an application (frontend + backend) with Nuxt.JS & Nest.JS and I would like to be able to deploy both applications in a single azure webapp.

So I used docker-compose to combine these two applications

I created my two applications nest and nuxt with their respective dockerfile but when I launch my azure webapp my application throws me a connection refused on the backend server address.

```
2021-01-04T14:25:40.285318405Z > app@1.0.0 start /src
2021-01-04T14:25:40.285328805Z > nuxt start
2021-01-04T14:25:40.285332905Z
2021-01-04T14:25:48.450602161Z ℹ Listening on: http://172.16.1.3:3000/
2021-01-04T14:27:27.474295806Z
2021-01-04T14:27:27.474325906Z  ERROR  getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND back back:5000
2021-01-04T14:27:27.474331907Z
2021-01-04T14:27:27.474336207Z   at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
2021-01-04T14:27:27.474340707Z
2021-01-04T14:27:27.502576941Z
2021-01-04T14:27:27.502597541Z  ERROR  getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND back back:5000
2021-01-04T14:27:27.502654542Z
2021-01-04T14:27:27.502660442Z   at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
2021-01-04T14:27:27.502664942Z
2021-01-04T14:43:42.908712507Z
2021-01-04T14:43:42.910087624Z  ERROR  getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND back back:5000
2021-01-04T14:43:42.910098524Z
2021-01-04T14:43:42.910103124Z   at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
2021-01-04T14:43:42.910107624Z
2021-01-04T14:43:42.942548608Z
2021-01-04T14:43:42.942574408Z  ERROR  getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND back back:5000
2021-01-04T14:43:42.942592008Z
2021-01-04T14:43:42.942598908Z   at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26)
2021-01-04T14:43:42.942605409Z
```

**What I tried**:

- I tried to create a docker compose network, but to my basic knowledge both applications are in the same virtual network with docker compose
- I tried to change the axios protocol
- I tried fetching on localhost, 127.0.0.1, 0.0.0.0.0, back, thomassaison-back address

And I really don't know how to solve this problem which is quite difficult to debug

**It's working locally**

**Here are my docker files:**

Nuxt Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile
FROM node:10-alpine

ENV APP_ROOT /src

RUN mkdir ${APP_ROOT}
WORKDIR ${APP_ROOT}
ADD . ${APP_ROOT}

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build

ENV HOST 0.0.0.0
```

Nest Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:10 AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build


FROM node:10-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=builder /app ./
CMD ["npm", "run", "start:prod"]
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  thomassaison-front:
    build: "./app/"
    container_name: "front"
    image: "thomassaison.azurecr.io/thomassaison-front"
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - thomassaison-back
    ports: 
      - "80:3000"
    command:
      "npm run start"
      

  thomassaison-back:
    build: "server/"
    container_name: "back"
    image: "thomassaison.azurecr.io/thomassaison-back"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
```

Azure WebApp docker-compose:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  thomassaison-front:
    image: "thomassaison.azurecr.io/thomassaison-front:latest"
    container_name: "front"
    depends_on:
      - thomassaison-back
    ports: 
      - "80:3000"
    command:
      "npm run start"
      

  thomassaison-back:
    image: "thomassaison.azurecr.io/thomassaison-back:latest"
    container_name: "back"
```

nuxt.config.js:

```
export default {
  // Global page headers (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head)
  head: {
    title: 'app',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
    ],
    link: [{ rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }],
  },

  // Global CSS (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css)
  css: [],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins)
  plugins: [],

  // Auto import components (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components)
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended) (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules)
  buildModules: [],

  // Modules (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules)
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/bootstrap
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/axios
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
  ],

  // Axios module configuration (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-axios)
  axios: {
    baseURL: 'https://back:5000',
  },

  // Build Configuration (https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build)
  build: {},
}
```

Comment: Is one of these components a browser-based application?  Your browser isn't in Docker, and so it will never be able to resolve the Docker-internal hostnames.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question, but Nuxt.js renders a Web application (SSR), and nuxt.js is my API, these two applications running in a nodejs environment

Comment: Any updates on this question? Does it solve you problem?

Comment: Yes, that solved my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Azure Web App, when you use the docker-compose to run multiple containers, then all the containers can communicate with each other via the port that other containers expose, they are using the same host. See the example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-multi-container-app), you need to set the environment variable and the option `depends_on` for the container that you want to connect:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:                          # here 
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306         # here
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data:
```

I'm not sure, but maybe you can change the value of baseURL into `https://thomassaison-back:5000` in the nuxt.config.js file, like the `depends_on` you set in the docker-compose.